# Tried to run pulseaudio

Tags: networking, 18.04, sound, pulseaudio

When I was trying to do [this](https://superuser.com/a/750324/1169109) It got me an error on running `pactl list | grep Name` command. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with linux deploy and LXDE desktop.

Error:

```
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
Connection failure: Connection refused
```

Edit: When I run `ps -ef | grep pulse`
It shows: `amir 11860 11845 0 21:57 pts/13 00:00:00 grep --color=auto pulse`

Comment: `ps -ef | grep pulse`  please add this to your question.

Comment: @nobody amir     11860 11845  0 21:57 pts/13   00:00:00 grep --color=auto pulse